# Upside down Triangle - While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to create this pattern with a while loop:

```
* * * *
 * * *
  * *
   *
```

This is the program that I have come up with, but, it keeps printing stars without repeatedly:

```
    i = 4
while i > 0:
    j = 1
    while j < 4 - 1:
        print(end = " ")
        k = 0
        while k < i:
            print("*",end = " ")
        print()
    i = i - 1
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong with my program?

Comment: You don't modify `j` inside the second loop, so the condition is always `True`. Similarly the third loop is an endless one.

Comment: You never get out of the "while k < i" loop, meaning that it will just keep printing stars.

Answer (score 0):

You never update j in the inner while loop, so j is always < 3. Increment j in your inner while loop and it won't repeat indefinitely. The same is true with k.

Alternatively, you can make the pattern with only one loop with something like this

```
start_i = 4
i = start_i
while i > 0:
    print(" " * (start_i - i) +  "* " * i)
    i -= 1
```